# Problems in LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding

1) In pattern, LUIS does not let you have more than 3 arguments using the OR operator, e.g (a|b|c|d) is illegal (why?)

2) In pattern, is there any way we can specify an optional text, something like "I want to [text] {entity}" so that the user can type in whatever between "to" and {entity} ?

3) In pattern, I cannot make the plural option for a word, e.g "How to contact the supplier[s]" doesn't work when the user types in "How to contact the suppliers". And I had to add "suppliers" to my entities list, which I find inconvenient

4) When you delete an intent, all the utterances automatically go to None intent. I think that should be an option "Do you want to move the utterances to None intent?"

Comment: 4) When you are deleting an intent then you are always prompted with: "Are you sure you want to delete intent "..." ? [_] Keep this intent's utterances in the None intent."

Comment: 3) you might want to use Entities. If the entity values are both supplier and suppliers then your pattern might look like "How to contact {ContactPerson}" if ContactPerson is the name of the respective entity.